# Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have a piece of code like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Изображение</label>
    <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="image" value="{{ old('image', $products->image) }}">
    @if($products->image)
       <img src="{{ Storage::url($products->image) }}" alt="" style="width: 150px">
    @endif
    @if ($errors->has('image'))
       <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong></span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I got the following error:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should
>   not be called statically

and I have Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);
    $file = request()->file('image') ? request()->file('image')->store('images', 'public') : null;
    $product = product::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'description' => $request['description'],
        'image' => $file,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('products.index', $product);
}
```

It's CRUD

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id) 
 {
    $this->validate($request, [ 'key' => 'required|string|max:255', // 'value' => 'required', ]); 
    $product = product::update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name'], // 'value' => $request['value'], ]); 
    return redirect()->route('products.show', $product); 
 }
```

Comment: Is your `Product` model really lowercase? Maybe `$product = product::create([` should be `$product = Product::create([`?

Comment: Where is your update statement?

Comment: Hey @Alisher your problem is in your update code you have shown us your store code, please show your update code and Please double check that your product class name is 'Product' or 'product'.

Comment: @n1njac0de 
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'key' => 'required|string|max:255',
            // 'value' => 'required',
        ]);
        $product = product::update([
            'key' => $request['key'],
            'name' => $request['name'],
            // 'value' => $request['value'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('products.show', $product);
    }

Comment: check my latest answer @AlisherADM

Comment: let me know if my answer work.

Answer (score 3):

Change line

```
$product = product::update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name'], // 'value' => $request['value'], ]);
```

To

```
$product = (new product)->update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name'], // 'value' => $request['value'], ]);
```

> Note: It is always advisable to follow the Laravel convention. So
> *Product* instead of *product* would be better for the model name. However, use the exact case of the class name. Your model file wasn't posted but since your `store` method worked fine, I believe you used `product` instead of `Product`

Answer (score 3):

You can use query builder as below...

```
DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->update(['value' => $request->value"]);
```

OR, you may use Eloquent as below...

```
Product::where('id', $id)->update(['value' => $request->value"]);
```

Your code should look like below...

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 'key' => 'required|string|max:255', // 'value' => 'required', ]); 
    $product = product::where('id', $id)->update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name'], // 'value' => $request['value'], ]); 
    return redirect()->route('products.show', $product); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Line:

```
  $product = product::update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name'], // 'value' => $request['value'], ]);
```

Change Line To: here 'product' will be table name

```
  DB::table('product')->update([ 'key' => $request['key'], 'name' => $request['name']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change your approach to update data. In order to update your data with Laravel or add where it will be help

convert this:

```
product::update([ 'key' => $request['key'],'name' => $request['name']);
```

to:

```
product::where('id',$id)->update([ 'key' => $request['key'],'name' => $request['name']);
```

or:

```
product::find($id)->update([ 'key' => $request['key'],'name' => $request['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    $file = request()->file('image') ? request()->file('image')->store('images', 'public') : null;
    $product = product::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'description' => $request['description'],
        'image' => $file,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

Comment: I got the following error:                                                                                              
 Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your approach to update data. In order to update your data with Laravel (in fact, not only Laravel but in generally all programming languages and query such as MySQL), you need to determine what record you want to update. In Laravel you can do that with `find` method. Sure, you can use another method like `WHERE`. So, for answer your problem, you can't do an update like to create. Therefore, your `update` method code should look like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'key' => 'required|string|max:255',
        // 'value' => 'required',
    ]);
    $product = Product::find($id); //get the object of product you want to update
    $product->key = $request['key'];
    $product->name = $request['name'];
    //$product->value = $request['value'];
    $product->save();

    return redirect()->route('products.show', $product);
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'key' in 'field list' (SQL: update `products` set `name` = wwwwwwwwwxxx, `updated_at` = 2018-12-28 09:52:14, `key` = test where `id` = 2)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'key' in 'field list' (SQL: update products set name = wwwwwwwwwxxx, updated_at = 2018-12-28 09:52:14, key = test where id = 2) –

Comment: It's another error tho. Your key column doesn't exist or your fillable array doesn't include `key` value

Comment: I also encourage you to post the code snippets of your product migration and model.

Comment: so how? Does it work already? If it does please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I asume you come from an update form, make sure your form's action is dynamic

```
<form action="{{ route ('products') }}/{{ $product->id }}" method="post">
@csrf 
@method('PATCH')
```